# gulp webserver and livereload

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have a problem with my gulp webserver. I have this gulp task:

```
gulp.task('serve', ['watch'], () => {
  gulp.src('tmp')
    .pipe(webserver({
      livereload: true,
      directoryListing: true,
      open: true,
      //defaultFile: 'index.html'
    }));
});
```

When running `gulp serve` I am getting the following screen on localhost:8000:
[image: localhost:8000]

It seems like that the webserver is serving the root directory of my project and not tmp folder, the odd thing is if I click the index.html I am redirected to `http://localhost:8000/index.html` which is the correct file (`tmp/index.html` and not `/index.html`).

I am using `gulp-webserver` for serving and live reload.

What did I do wrong?

Note: uncommenting the defaultFile doesn't help.

Comment: if it for dev only, you should take a look at `browserSync` instead of using webserver

Comment: @ArnaudGueras Browsersync - https://browsersync.io/docs/gulp worked straight away for me - thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass an object into directoryListing to adjust this setting.

```
.pipe(webserver({
  directoryListing: {
    enable: true,
    path: 'tmp'
  }
}));
```

Details:
https://github.com/schickling/gulp-webserver#options

Comment: It does not wait for the dependent tasks to complete and triggers the page reload as soon as any source file is changed. It requires a manual page refresh. Can this be fixed too?

Answer (score 1):

**open** can be also a string.By providing a String you can specify the path to open (for complete path, use the complete url http://my-server:8080/public/) .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    gulp.task('serve', ['watch'], () => {
      gulp.src('./tmp')
      .pipe(webserver({
      livereload: true,
      directoryListing: true,
      open: true,
      //defaultFile: 'index.html'
     }));
   });
```